# Three.js object3d.translateZ causes NaN in all position values

Tags: javascript, three.js

It seems that when I use `translate[X|Y|Z]` on my object, its position gets mangled and only contains `NaN` values.

[image: weird]

Three.js r70

The position is relative, the absolute is different:
[image: comparison]

My code

```
if (!this.following) return false;

var mesh = this.get(); //One mesh
this.mesh.lookAt(this.mesh.worldToLocal((new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)).setFromMatrixPosition(this.following.whom.matrixWorld))); //this.following.whom is another mesh

var followerPosition = mesh.localToWorld(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
var followeePosition = this.following.whom.localToWorld(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
var distance = followerPosition.distanceTo(followeePosition);

if (distance > this.following.distance) { //this.following.distance is scalar value
    mesh.translateZ(distance * 0.02);
}

return true;
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I not use transformZ when dealing with relative values?

Comment: what exactly is your code. you are only showing results.

Comment: Use the non-minified version of three.js and step through with the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I missed important thing. If rotation of an object is `NaN`, the translation will fail.